# How to abort Fight Flash Fraud (F3)?

Tags: command-line, process, kill

I am using the commands `f3write` and `f3probe` and want to abort them. There is no consideration of this in the manual and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is not working. I can kill the process in task manager but I was wondering if that is healthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ending the process or killing it should be fine. More info from [this Gnome page](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-system-monitor/stable/process-kill.html.en):

> If a program stops working or freezes, you can force it to close ("kill" it) using *System Monitor*. Go to the **Processes** tab and click to select the process you want to kill. Then, click **End Process**.
>
> If the process does not close after a few seconds, right-click it and select **Kill** from the menu that appears.
>
> Using **End Process** tries to close the process properly, giving it time to save files and so on, whereas **Kill** forces it to close straight away. For some programs, this might mean that you lose unsaved files. You should always try **End Process** first.

So given that `f3write` already deletes all data on the tested disk, there is no concern about losing unsaved files when killing the process.

---

By the way, from the command line, you can put the program in the background with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then do the equivalent of **End Process** with `kill %1`, or do the equivalent of **Kill** with `kill -9 %1`. If you already have background jobs running, replace `%1` as needed.

Source: [When should I not kill -9 a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8916/117037)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the end of the world, but external storage on linux does seem like it can get confused sometimes, if things don't work after you kill it, you might need to reboot.